# Excel 2007 keeps changing conditional format row reference to 1048576

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2007, superuser

I'm constructing a series of spreadsheets that will be used as a checklist and setting up conditional formatting so that if a particular item has been checked, a user enters "y" in the next cell over and both the cell containing the checklist item and the cell containing the "y" both turn green.

For example, if column A contains the list items, column B will be blank to enter "y" as items are completed. I'm setting up conditional formatting with the formula: =$B2="y" and selecting to apply this to =$A$2:$B$50

This all works perfectly when I have it set up in the Conditional Formatting Rules Manager window, but as soon as I click ok or apply, Excel ruins all of my formulas. It changes the formula from =$B2="y" to =$B1048576="y". It doesn't stop me from editing the formula and changing the value back to 2, but I'm not sure why it is doing this. I believe it is that same number every time, but honestly I haven't kept track.

As I have to apply this formatting to ~50 workbooks, this is getting super annoying. Anyone know what the cause is or how to make excel stop messing with my formula?

My excel level is probably basic/intermediate

PS. My workplace refuses to upgrade to modern software and we're stuck with office '07. If this is an excel bug I might be able to use that as some leverage to finally get an upgrade, any info would be helpful.

Comment: Is there a VBA connection here?  If not then this question might be better-suited to SuperUser

Answer (score 2):

your formula is fine, however change your application method.  To make your life easier, delete your current entry as the formula is rather short.  if the real formula is complex, consider editing the formula and then copying it to memory before deleting it.

When assigning conditional formatting with a cell reference that is not locked, I select my table or ranges first and then make sure the left most upper cell is the active cell.

I then enter my formula in conditional formatting and hit apply.  The cell in the formula will adjust itself based on what the active cell was when it was entered it seems.  When I have done this and the active cell was in the bottom right corner of my selection, I would get really screwy (technical term) numbers in my formula after and the conditional formatting would not work as intended.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I'm trying to follow you here, but I'm not sure what you mean by " I select my table or ranges first and then make sure the left most upper cell is the active cell"

How do I select a range of cells and pick one as "active"?

Comment: select your table range first is the same way you select a range to copy.  You click on a cell and drag.  Your selected range will have a slightly grey background usually and a border will show up around it.  The active cell will be the cell within this range that is a bright usually white background.  the active cell is also the last cell you initiate a "click" on when selecting your  range.  So if you click on B3 and drag D12,  The  last cell you initiated a click on would be B3 which in turn in you active cell.  If instead you  click on D12 and dragged up and to the left to B3, the last

Comment: cell you initiated a click on would be D12 and it would be your active cell.  Of the two methods, you want to use the one that has the active cell in the left most and upper corner so you would want to choose the method that made B3 the active cell.

Comment: I also answered this similar question on [conditional formatting here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37288092/conditional-formatting-for-a-column-based-on-the-value-of-header/37288810#37288810).  It is mostly just a repeat of what I just said but thought I would include it in case it explained things slightly differently.