# Conditional formatting for a column based on the value of header

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2013, conditional-formatting

I have several columns where the data from rows 7 onwards changes depending on the selection made from a dropdown menu in row 6. Most of these options will result in textual or number based values appearing, but two of them would need to be formatted as currency.

Essentially what I want is a conditional formatting formula that says; if row six in any column has a value of “Implied Unit Rate” or “Annual budget”, format rows 7 and onwards in that column as currency.

I can get this to work by creating two separate conditional formatting formulas and applying them both to the whole area, but it seems like there should be a way to do it in a single formula.

My current formulas, applied as two separate rules:

`=INDIRECT(ADDRESS(6,COLUMN(),1))="Annual Budget"`

`=INDIRECT(ADDRESS(6,COLUMN(),1))="Implied Unit Rate"`

How I think it should work when applied as one rule:

`=OR(INDIRECT(ADDRESS(6,COLUMN(),1))="Annual Budget",
     INDIRECT(ADDRESS(6,COLUMN(),1))="Implied Unit Rate")`

When I enter the combined formula in a regular cell within the worksheet, it does return true as expected, but does nothing when I apply it as a conditional formatting rule. Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Not your problem but giving another option than the volatile function INDIRECT(). `=OR(INDEX($6:$6,COLUMN())="Annual Budget",INDEX($6:$6,COLUMN())="Implied Unit Rate")`  You problem probably stems from the applies to:.

Comment: Success! Agree that it's cleaner and avoids the INDIRECT function, but don't really understand the difference that would make it work in this context where the other combined OR function wouldn't. Thank you Scott.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now I may be mis interpreting what Scott is saying, so I am going to say this in my own words.

Your condition check on the cell address in question is a little "verbose".  In order to apply your conditional formatting, select the range you want to apply your condition formatting to first.  Lets arbitrarily say select range A7 to D42.  After selecting the appropriate range, ensure cell A7 is the active cell of the selected range.  This usually means there is a border around A7 to D42 and all cells but A7 have been slightly greyed to indicate that they have been selected, and A7 will have a brighter background to indicate that it is the active cell.  With all that still in effect, select your conditional formatting.

In conditional formatting choose formula as the option (last one at the bottom) to control how your formatting will be applied.  In the region where you can enter your formula, enter the following:

```
=OR(A$6="Annual Budget", A$6="Implied Unit Rate")
```

The $ will keep the row and column reference from changing as it is applied to each cell in the range.  It will always be checking row 6 of what ever column the cell is in.  The column A reference is relative to the active cell.

Comment: Not quite sorry Ed. I only want to format the column where row 6 in that colum has either of those values.

Comment: And the enter key submits a comment apparently... Noted! Continuing on...

So lets say A6=Annual Budget, B6=Quantity, C6=Project, D6=Implied Unit Rate; then only A and D would need formatting, while B and C would stay as general.

Then lets say that the user changed the value of D6 to something else, column D would change it's formatting back to general. Or the reverse if you changed any cell in row 6 back to Budget or Unit Rate.

Your solution appears to apply the formatting to the entire range if any cell in row 6 has the specified value.

Comment: OK that was my first approach hold on and I will edit

Comment: See revamped formula and slightly edited explination. The key is having the active cell of your selection in the top right corner so as the conditional formula is applied to each cell, the addresses in the formula will update with respect to the active cell.  Goes bonkers when I have done this with the bottom right cell as the active cell.

Comment: Success! Thank you Ed.

I had always assumed that conditional formatting formulas applied the formula as if that exact formula had been entered in the given cell. Nice to know that it is in fact relative to the active cell! A much simpler solution than what I had and I learned a general principal which I’m sure can be applied in the future. Cheers.

Comment: FYI it also works with non contiguous ranges.  The trick is getting the active cell to the left most and upper position without losing your selection.